# How can I have a column separator after an equals sign in an "aligned" environment?

Tags: math-mode

I understand that the "aligned" environment is meant to be used like this:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
A &= bc \\
&= cd
\end{aligned}
\]
```

This works and looks quite nice.

But what if both the `A` part and the `bc` part are quite long, and I want to have them on their own separate lines, so that each line except the first has an equals sign at the beginning?

This is what I tried:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
& A \\
=& bc \\
=& cd
\end{aligned}
\]
```

Unfortunately this makes it so that there is no space after the equals signs, which looks weird.

How can I have an equation in this format but have the correct spacing after the equals sign (as in the first example)?

Comment: Add `{}` on the left side (or on the rightside, or both) of the `=` signes. This being said; you should post a representative example code of the difficullties you're meeting.

Comment: Change the instances of `=&` to `&=`.